# Initialize struct array in header with void function

Tags: c++, arrays, header-files

I'm just learning c++. I wonder if it's legal to initialize my array like this? My goal is to avoid a very very long list of arrays in the cpp. 
If not what should I do to be legal ? Visual Studio does not underline errors but application failed and crash at beginning.

**in header.h :**

```
#ifndef _INC_HEADER_H
#define _INC_HEADER_H

struct symname{ char* DP; };

struct symname getSymName[4];

void init_allArrays(){
        getSymName[0].DP = "name0";
        getSymName[1].DP = "name1"; 
        getSymName[2].DP = "name2"; 
        getSymName[3].DP = "name3"; 
}

#endif // _INC_HEADER_H
```

**now in my main.cpp :**

```
#include "header.h" 

init_allArrays() ; 

char * test = getSymName[0].DP  // can i acceed to the array at this point ?!
```

Comment: Use standard collections and don't use globals. Then all of your problems will go away, I think.

Comment: You didn't declare the struct anywhere, so you can't fill the array.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? Read about the "Static Initialization Fiasco" for a more thorough answer to why the way you are attempting to do this is not a good approach. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order  edit: this assumes that the code you are running, is in main.cpp but outside of main()

Comment: @Evan Carslake  I declared the struct in header and because i included it in main i thouth its enought , should i redeclare structure in main ? why twice ?

Comment: @guillaumeimportexport Usually you let a compiler process your code, and it will tell you if that syntax was right or not. Also, where do you actually allocate memory for `DP`?

Comment: it compiled without errors but crash when program start and i know pb is here because when i fill the array in main , crash desapear

Comment: don't assign a string literal to a `char *`.  use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::vector<std::string>` probably.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would use a `std::array` if the size is never going to change.

Comment: where do you actually allocate memory for DP? i'm sorry i don't understand the question

Comment: @guillaumeimportexport That may identify your basic problem, that you don't see, why you need to allocate memory, before you can do something like `getSymName[0].DP = "name0";`.

Comment: `getSymName[0].DP = "name0";` is valid, though must likely unintended. Without compiler optimizations, `"name0"` will exist in the text portion of the runtime environment and the pointer will be set to that address. Modifying that memory will cause the program to crash.

Comment: i never modify getSymName[0].DP , i would use it at very static table data

Comment: @RyanP It might not give you an error but it is not standard: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/578c5cf730ad4ddf

Comment: @guillaumeimportexport Even if you don't use it in a way that will cause the program to crash, it still isn't a good idea to do it. Just giving one reason that it might allow your program to compile but then crash.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's complaining that you are converting a `const char*` to a `char*`. Some compilers will let you get away with it, some won't, some depend on warning level settings. I assume his compiler is letting him do it. Here is the same thing modified with `const char*`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b68d8f6ba07fffd7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to assign a string literal ( "this is a string literal" ) to a character pointer. It is undefined behavior to modify that string literal and will cause your program to crash.

As mentioned, in general you want to use std::string as well as shy away from global variables if possible.

Additionally, it looks like this is run outside of a function like main(), therefore you should read isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

What that article gets at is that you aren't guaranteed an order during runtime for how globals/statics get initialized, so what if `char * test = getSymName[0].DP` is run before `init_allArrays() ;`? That would be bad, but also might only happen 50% of the time causing unpredictable crashes.

Comment: so what if char * test = getSymName[0].DP is run before init_allArrays() ;?  i understand , how can i avoid that ?

Comment: @guillaumeimportexport it is the next section: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use

Comment: @guillaumeimportexport Also, I'd make sure you are using strings instead of char*, you have to know a bit about memory allocation/deallocation to work with char* and unless you really need them, it isn't worth it.